# Collapsing if statement with Go

Tags: go

I had this:

```
  i := 0
  for _, key := range keys {
    i++
    if i > min {
      break
    }
    var inf = val.MapIndex(key)
    if inf.IsValid() && inf.CanInterface() {
      z.Val[key] = getInspectableVal(inf.Interface(), 0)
    } else {
      z.Val[key] = nil
    }
  }
```

being a naturally unsatisfiable person, I tried this:

```
  i := 0
  for _, key := range keys {
    if i++; i > min {
      break
    }
    var inf = val.MapIndex(key)
    if inf.IsValid() && inf.CanInterface() {
      z.Val[key] = getInspectableVal(inf.Interface(), 0)
    } else {
      z.Val[key] = nil
    }
  }
```

I cannot confirm if this is valid go or if it's doing what want it to do (what it's doing originally).

Comment: "I cannot confirm if this is valid go", did you compile it? If it compiles, it's valid go.

Comment: it compiles - it is valid - but what it do?

Comment: do it do what I want it to do without exception?

Comment: What does this have to do with intellij-idea or jetbrains-ide?

Comment: You can check the spec for [`if` statements](https://go.dev/ref/spec#If_statements): _"The expression may be preceded by a simple statement, which executes before the expression is evaluated."_

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that keys is a slice, you can use this code:

```
for _, key := range keys[:min(len(keys), minimum)] {
    var inf = val.MapIndex(key)
    if inf.IsValid() && inf.CanInterface() {
        z.Val[key] = getInspectableVal(inf.Interface(), 0)
    } else {
        z.Val[key] = nil
    }
}
```

where `min` is the builtin function and `minimum` is the application's minimum value.

The idea here is to range over a slice of the desired length rather than break out of the loop after the count is reached.